# how to set dti fields to entity class with stream api

Tags: java, spring, stream

Hi brothers and sisters can i solve this method with stream api i try but i can't

```java
public Response addDetail(DetailDto detailDto) {
        Optional<Orders> ordersOptional = orderRepo.findById(detailDto.getOrderId());
        if (ordersOptional.isEmpty()) return new Response("it is order not found", false);
        Optional<Product> productOptional = productRepo.findById(detailDto.getProductId());
        if (productOptional.isEmpty()) return new Response("it is product not found", false);
        Detail detail = new Detail();
        detail.setOrders(ordersOptional.get());
        detail.setProduct(productOptional.get());
        detail.setQuantity(detailDto.getQuantity());
        detailRepo.save(detail);
        return new Response("order saved successfully", true);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything that could be improved with streams here.

Comment: my friend said to me if you have many field to set you can set with stream api with short code but i can't it